# WAS 7.0 JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated

Tags: java, web-services, axis, websphere-7

I have a problem about WAS 7.0 class loading constraint problem I see a solution for a problem which is similar to mine, at Stackoverflow(exclude xmlbeans jar from your pom) However this solution didn't work for me. I think my problem is different

```
`com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[project]: java.lang.VerifyError JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/axis/message/NodeImpl, method=getParentNode()Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;, pc=0
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2364)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at service.MyserviceStub.getFirstRequest(MyserviceStub.java:350)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

IBM website has [support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249) describing your issue.